ECMAScript in Apache Wicket
Is Apache Wicket supported for ECMAScript 6, or is Ajax or jQuery always required to be integrated? Can this be found in a document? I am writing my master thesis and I try to compare TypeScript with Apache Wicket
I was searching in Google Scholar to find an answer

TypeScript is a programming language. Apache Wicket is a Java web framework. You are comparing apples to oranges.

Wicket is a server-side web framework and, as such, it gives you control on the generated page code that is returned to a web client. So it doesn't depend on any JavaScript library or version. That said, it also comes with some AJAX-enabled components and behaviors that comes with the required JavaScript to support server side callbacks via AJAX. As of Wicket 10 this JavaScript code depends on JQuery.
Hope this could help you.
